# Creating filled center points as centers from clusters in a ggplot2 visualisation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
point_duration1 = rnorm(n=100, mean=8, sd=1.5)
point_duration2 = rnorm(n=100, mean=9, sd=1.5)
point_duration3 = rnorm(n=100, mean=7, sd=2)
point_duration_test <- c(point_duration1, point_duration2, point_duration3)

point_silence1 = rnorm(n=100, mean=0.3, sd=0.1)
point_silence2 = rnorm(n=100, mean=0.25, sd=0.15)
point_silence3 = rnorm(n=100, mean=0.15, sd=0.1)
point_silence_test <- c(point_silence1, point_silence2, point_silence3)

df_test <- data.frame(point_duration = point_duration_test, point_silence = point_silence_test)
df_test$point_silence <- ifelse((df_test$point_silence < 0),0,df_test$point_silence)
df_test$group <- 1
df_test[1:100,]$group <- 2
```

Which I use to create the following visualisation:

```
ggplot(df_test, aes(x = point_duration, y = point_silence, colour = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=df_test %>% 
               group_by(group) %>% 
               summarise(point_duration = mean(point_duration), point_silence = mean(point_silence)),
             size=10, shape=1)
```

This works, however I would like to create a solid and filled center point instead of the hollow one Im getting now. I cant find a way to fill the center points though... Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Prefer `shape = 16` or `shape = 19` if you need a filled point.

Comment: [tag:ggplot]'s shapes have the same numbering as base `plot`'s `pch` values. As @bVa suggests values you'd find 15-20 is best for automatic fill. Over that you'll have to specfy the background color.

Comment: I use `shape = 21`, then map `fill` instead of `color`.